# Get the original url in this case with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In the form below, I change the action attribute and submit the form. That works fine. What goes on is: if the current location is `http://localhost/search/?mod=all` and the search term is 14, the action will be changed to `http://localhost/search/?mod=all&handle=14` and so will the url in the browser.

But the next time I try to search, since the url now is `http://localhost/search/?mod=all&handle=14`, I get `http://localhost/search/?mod=all&handle=14&handle=15`. It'll keep going on and on with each search term.

Any idea how I can retain the orginal url `http://localhost/search/?mod=all` through this all.

Here's the form:

```
<form method="GET" class="modForm" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="modSearchValue">
<input type="radio" name="text" value="text" class="text" title="Search">
</form>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$('.modForm').submit(function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var query = $this.find('.modSearchValue').val(); // Use val() instead of attr('value').
  var locale = window.location;
  if ($('.text').is(':checked')) {
    query = '&text=' + query;
  } else {
    query = '&handle=' + query;
  }
  route = locale + query;
  console.log(route);
  if (query.length >= 1) {
    // Use URI encoding
    var newAction = (route);
    console.log(newAction); // DEBUG
    // Change action attribute
    $this.attr('action', newAction);
    //event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid search terms'); // DEBUG
    // Do not submit the form
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: His second paragraph states the problem with the code.

Comment: There's no problem with the code. It's the URL. I need to keep or get the original one.

Comment: He clearly knows of the `window.location` object and its basic use as well. Read his code snippet.

Comment: well, this was very useful and see my answer :)

Comment: Whay do you have a _only one_ radio? Why not use a checkbox instead?

Comment: @SalmanA The radio is ok. It's the url that's the problem. See my question.

Comment: @Norman: see my answer. I used checkbox but you could use radio instead (with minor tweaks).

Comment: Really though, you should use a checkbox. Checkboxes are designed to be toggled on and off individually, while radio buttons are designed to be part of a group. This is a user interface construct that most people are used to, so your app will feel more professional if it uses the UI elements as designed. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to do it. I would rather not mess with window.location and do something simpler:

```
<form method="GET" class="modForm" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="mod" value="all"> <!-- mod is a hidden variable -->
    <input type="text" id="modSearchValue">      <!-- name not defined yet -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="textOrHandle">    <!-- name not required -->
</form>
```

```javascript
$(".modForm").submit(function() {
    $("#modSearchValue").attr("name", $("#textOrHandle").is(":checked") ? "text" : "handle");
    // let the form submit!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do it. Why can't you store original URL in a global variable (kept outside your functions like form submit etc.)

If you do not want that you can use window.location.hash which will return all the GET params you are sending. Using split you will be able to get exact parameter that you want. If you still need help, I will post the code.

Comment: That url will change. `http://localhost/search/?mod=all` or `http://localhost/search/?mod=del` etc

Comment: `window.location.hash` contains the part of the URL after `#`, not the query string. ITYM `window.location.search`.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution: If, for this code, `window.location` should always be `http://localhost/search/?mod=all`, then you don't even need to say `var locale = window.location`. Just say `var locale = "http://localhost/search/?mod=all"` and you avoid the problem.

Comment: That url keeps changing. `http://localhost/search/?mod=all` can also be `http://localhost/search/?mod=del` or `http://localhost/search/?mod=top` etc etc

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll edit the "real solution" into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
​var s = window.location.hostname; // gets the hostname
var d = window.location.protocol; // gets the protocol
var g = window.location.search; // gets all the params
var x = g.split("&"); // split each parameter
var url = d+"//"+s+x[0]; // makes url you want
alert(url);​​​​ // just for chill
```